# Проверка размерности

Tags: php

```
if(strpos($num,'%')!==false && intval($num)>0){
  $num - intval($num)*$maxNum/100;
}
```

Надо проверить размерность (%,etc.) сравнить с нулем и выяснить: число ли было введено.
Ничего умнее кучи intval и strpos не придумал.

Еще есть такой вариант:

```
preg_match('/^\d+(%|px)$/',$num,$match);
```

Но он кажется хоть и более красивым, но более затратным. Экономлю на спичках?

**Вопрос:**
Как красиво и быстро отделить корректный ввод числа с размерностью от всякой остальной фигни и привести к заранее известной размерности в случае корректного ввода?

Гм. Тянет на учебное задание. *confused*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экономите на спичках, так-же не забывайте что число процентов может быть float, например 33.33%, переделка REGEXP - не сильно сложнее, а с первым примером придется помучится...

Regexp для float значений:

```
preg_match('/^([\d.]+)(%|px)$/',$num,$match);
```

тогда получится $match[1] - значение, $match[2] - размерность.

Comment: Verstehen. Значит все же через регэксп. 
Насчет значений: пока что они могут быть только целыми, но идею внедрить дробные учту.

Comment: да, если уж быть точным (у заначения может быть знак):

    preg_match('/^([+-]?[\d.]+)(%|px)$/',$num,$match);

Плюс есть еще экспонентциальная форма записи :-)

    preg_match('/^([\d.eE+-]+)(%|px)$/',$num,$match);